# Wifi connection hanging when 'getting IP configuration'

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, wifi, network-interface

I've got the same issue as described here. 
[My Linux Mint can't connect to WiFi, it keeps saying connecting but never actually connects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555590/my-linux-mint-cant-connect-to-wifi-it-keeps-saying-connecting-but-never-actual/579909#579909)

It was never answered.

The output of mncli is

GENERAL.DEVICE: wlp202 GENERAL.TYPE: wifi GENERAL.HWADDR: 80:C6:etcetera GENERAL.MTU: 1500 GENERAL.STATE: 50 (connecting (configuring)) GENERAL.CONNECTION: WIFI GENERAL.CON-PATH: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/43

When I redo that (without doing anything else in between) I now get

GENERAL.STATE: 70 (connecting (getting IP configuration)) GENERAL.CON-PATH: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/52 and the rest is the same

Every time I issue the command the last number changes

Answer (score 3):

I found that my clock was set to 2117-08-17. This likely was because before the issue arose, the computer ran out of battery. That fixed it.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=801805 gave me the idea to look for the system time